# Unpack all variadic template arguments except last one as type of variable

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I have a template class that accepts a variable number of types as arguments. The constructor accepts a pointer to an instance of the class that uses `Args... - 1` as parameter type. Searching over the internet I found out that a `std::tuple` is often used to handle this type of problems, but I don't understand how I could take the template arguments, create a tuple, remove the last type and then unpack the tuple again and store the result in a variable that can be retrieved later by the `parent()` function.

```
template<typename ...Args>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(MyClass<Args...> *parent) : parent_(parent) // Should be Args - 1
   {
   }

    MyClass<Args...>* parent()
    {
        return parent_;
    }

private:
    MyClass<Args...> *parent_;
};
```

I found different answers here on StackOverflow about similar topics that involve tuples. This code has been posted on another question and should get a tuple with all parameters except the last one. The problem is that I don't know how to adapt it to unpack that tuple again.

```
template<typename, typename>
struct concat_tuple { };

template<typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct concat_tuple<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::tuple<Us...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<Ts..., Us...>;
};

template <class T>
struct remove_last;

template <class T>
struct remove_last<std::tuple<T>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

template <class T, class... Args>
struct remove_last<std::tuple<T, Args...>>
{
    using type = typename concat_tuple<std::tuple<T>, typename remove_last<std::tuple<Args...>>::type>::type;
};
```

Comment: There's everything all right with your code (as long as you leaves Args uncommented) Maybe you didn't get the creator method public... Remember that default class member access modificator is private...

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg OP doesn't know how to unpack the tuple from `remove_last::type`

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg Commented Args was just a typo :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

template <template <typename...> class C, typename... Args, std::size_t... Is>
auto pop_back(std::index_sequence<Is...>) noexcept
    -> C<std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::tuple<Args...>>...>&&;

template <typename... Args>
class MyClass
{
    using Parent = std::remove_reference_t<
                      decltype(pop_back<::MyClass, Args...>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args) - 1>{}))
                   >;

public:    
    explicit MyClass(Parent* parent) : parent_(parent)
    {

    }

    Parent* parent()
    {
        return parent_;
    }

private:
    Parent* parent_;
};

template <>
class MyClass<> {};

int main()
{
    MyClass<> a;
    MyClass<int> b(&a);    
    MyClass<int, char> c(&b);
    MyClass<int, char, float> d(&c);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/161beebaaaccbedd)

---

The answer for the previous question, before the edit:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename... Args>
class MyClass
{
public:    
    auto newInstance()
    {
        return newInstance(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args) - 1>{});
    }

private:        
    template <std::size_t... Is>
    MyClass<typename std::tuple_element<Is, std::tuple<Args...>>::type...> newInstance(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return {};
    }
};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75e35bc8bfa17cdc)

---

> *Why the pop_back function has no body?*

This is actually a trait implemented in terms of a function declaration. Alternatively, you could use a more classic solution with a structure specialization:

```
template <typename T, typename S>
struct pop_back;

template <template <typename...> class C, typename... Args, std::size_t... Is>
struct pop_back<C<Args...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using type = C<std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::tuple<Args...>>...>;
};
```

and then use:

```
using Parent = typename pop_back<MyClass, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args) - 1>>::type;
```

That is, I used a function declaration to shorten the syntax. And it doesn't require a body, since noone is supposed to call this function in an evaluated context.

> *Why are you using noexcept?*

Imagine you have a function:

```
void foo(MyClass<int, char>) noexcept {}
```

And elsewhere you want to check whether the call is `noexcept`:

```
static_assert(noexcept(foo(pop_back<MyClass, int, char, float>(std::index_sequence<0, 1>{}))), "!");
```

Without the `noexcept` specifier, the above assertion would fail, since the call to `pop_back` would be considered as possibly throwing code.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer, it works. However, after some struggling with my own code I had to edit the question to reflect the recent changes to my code. As you can see, I don't have anymore the need to create a new instance of the class, but instead it must be passed as constructor parameter and so stored as member variable.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you. Could you please explain what the code does and two more questions: why the pop_back function has no body and why are you using noexcept?